# How to call a string from another function

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop, scanf

This is for a school assignment where we're learning how to use functions, and I'm getting an error on the 'while' line and the fscanf line after that.

```html
<?php

    openFile($fin);
    loadFile($fin);
 
 function openFile($fin) {
  $fin = fopen("employees.txt", "r") or die("File not found!");
 }

 function loadFile(&$fin) {
  fscanf($fin, "%s%s%f", $emp[$i][0],$emp[$i][1],$emp[$i][2]);
  while(!feof(&$fin)) {
   $i = $i + 1; 
   fscanf($fin, "%s%s%f", $emp[$i][0],$emp[$i][1],$emp[$i][2]);
  }
 }
  
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide the values of $emp and the output error log please. Will make it a bit easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this add &  openFile($fin) and remove & from while(!feof(&$fin))

```
openFile($fin);
loadFile($fin);

function openFile(&$fin) {
    $fin = fopen("demo.html", "r") or die("File not found!");
}

function loadFile(&$fin) {
    $i=0;
    fscanf($fin, "%s%s%f", $emp[$i][0],$emp[$i][1],$emp[$i][2]);
    while(!feof($fin)) {
        $i = $i + 1; 
        fscanf($fin, "%s%s%f", $emp[$i][0],$emp[$i][1],$emp[$i][2]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update

```
loadFile(openFile($fin));

function openFile($fin) {
    return fopen("employees.txt", "r") or die("File not found!");

}

function loadFile(&$fin) {
    fscanf($fin, "%s%s%f", $emp[$i][0],$emp[$i][1],$emp[$i][2]);
    while(!feof(&$fin)) {
        $i = $i + 1; 
        fscanf($fin, "%s%s%f", $emp[$i][0],$emp[$i][1],$emp[$i][2]);
    }
}

?>
```